# How to print this output in text file in java?

Tags: java, file, io

I have calculated the words and now displaying it in console. But I want to write the console output to a text file. how to do this?

```
String[] wrds   = counter.getWords(WordCounter.SortOrder.BY_FREQUENCY);
int[] frequency = counter.getFrequencies(WordCounter.SortOrder.BY_FREQUENCY);        

int n = counter.getEntryCount();
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
    This should be written in text file///// System.out.println(frequency[i] + " " + wrds[i]+" "+ counter.getWordCount());
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for tutorials on this at all? There is a plethora of great examples if you just google "java writing out to a file" or similar.

Comment: I googled your exact question title.  This is my 2nd hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994255/how-to-write-console-output-to-a-txt-file

Comment: All friends. I tried the example 1994255 but its not working

Comment: if it isn't working, then post the error (stacktrace) you got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] wrds   = counter.getWords(WordCounter.SortOrder.BY_FREQUENCY);
int[] frequency = counter.getFrequencies(WordCounter.SortOrder.BY_FREQUENCY);        
String texttoWrite = "";
int n = counter.getEntryCount();
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
    texttoWrite += frequency[i] + " " + wrds[i]+" "+ counter.getWordCount();
}
try{
 FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
 out.write(texttoWrite);
 out.close();
 }catch (Exception e){
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
 }
}
```

Comment: Updated the code. Try it.

Comment: thanks but I want to write as line by line.
{
    texttoWrite += frequency[i] + " " + wrds[i]+" "+ counter.getWordCount()+"\n";
}

is it correct?

Comment: Yes. You have to append a new line escape character to print line by line.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(fileName);
BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    fbw.write(frequency[i] + " " + wrds[i]+" "+ counter.getWordCount()+ "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("path location");
fw.write(frequency[i]....);
fw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a file with the file object. And write to the file in stead of the console (or do both). Close the file. What is the real problem?