# Output console into text file? - Java

Tags: java, console, text-files

Given my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AccountTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account1 = new Account(50.00);
        Account account2 = new Account(0.00);

        System.out.printf("account1 balance: $%.2f\n", account1.getBalance());
        System.out.printf("account2 balance: $%.2f\n\n", account2.getBalance());

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter withdrawal amount for account1: ");

        double withdrawalAmount = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.printf("\nsubtracting %.2f from account1 balance\n",
                withdrawalAmount);

        account1.debit(withdrawalAmount);

        System.out.printf("account1 balance: $%.2f\n", account1.getBalance());
        System.out.printf("account2 balance: $%.2f\n\n", account2.getBalance());

        System.out.print("Enter withdrawal amount for account2: ");
        withdrawalAmount = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("\nsubtracting %.2f from account2 balance\n",
                withdrawalAmount);
        account2.debit(withdrawalAmount);

        System.out.printf("account1 balance: $%.2f\n", account1.getBalance());
        System.out.printf("account2 balance: $%.2f\n", account2.getBalance());
    }
}
```

How can I get my "System.out.printf" dumped into a file (dumped as in  not erasing the file's content)? Or perhaps creating separate files for each instance. Any help is appreciated beginner here. Thanks.

Comment: Already an answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994255/how-to-write-console-output-to-a-txt-file?rq=1

Comment: If I am not mistaken that will read an input line then save to text file. Note that in my code I do not intend to input anything at all on the console.

Comment: @user2077545 Check out the top rated answer in that question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1994283/1211906

Comment: Yeah but that just replaces the file's content which I was hoping to avoid. Not to mention that all my lines are smashed together in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) you can redirect stdout to a file when running your program

```
java AccountTest >> test.txt
```

2) you can reassign stdout at the beginning of your program

```
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("test.txt", true));
    System.setOut(out);
```

3) you can use java.io.PrintWriter instead of System.out

```
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt", true));
    out.printf( "account1 balance: $%.2f\n", account1.getBalance() );
```

Comment: That line gave me the error: unreported exception IOExecption; declared to be thrown

Comment: this will help: main(String[] args) throws Exception

Comment: That worked but it is still replacing the dump file's content with each new instance.

Comment: How do I implement #1 into my code so I can test it. I am clueless.

Comment: dont change anything in the code, just run your program from command line java AccountTest >> test.txt

Comment: Works like a charm with two exceptions: 1) The statements never appear in console and 2) The statement get mashed together when imported to file.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is for the text file to look like the console print out.

Comment: it's not so easy to have both if you are in Windows, theres a workaround: java AccountTest >> test.txt && type test.txt

Comment: What if I was running on another OS?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you run this program. If you have a POSIX shell at hand, you can just redirect its standard output to a file.

The following would append to a log file:

```
$ java -jar myjar.jar >> log
```

this one would create a new epoch-dated log file each time (the `$(…)` might be a bash-specific feature, I'm not sure):

```
$ java -jar myjar.jar > log-$(date +%s)
```

Comment: I run it on the Windows command prompt.