# Write the console output over several runs to a text file

Tags: java

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994255/how-to-write-console-output-to-a-txt-file). However, I am looking for a way to append the text file over several runs. is there a way to write console output to a text file without erasing the old runs information? I am working on 30+ classes and it would be tedious to change `System.out.println` statements so I prefer sticking with the `System.setOut` solution.

I have the following code based on @Mac answer

```
   PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("aa.txt"),true);
   System.setOut(out);
```

but the file `aa.txt`does not append the results, am I missing something here?

Comment: 3 great answers within minutes is really a great surprise. Thanks all

Comment: No, it is NOT a duplicate of that question.  Read carefully - it is asking something quite different.

Comment: Did you try `new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("aa.txt",true))` ?  As I said in my comment on Mac's answer, he/she had the parentheses wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a `FileWriter` or `FileOutputStream` for your file, pass `true` as a second argument to the constructor of the `FileWriter` or `FileOutputStream`.

```
FileWriter(File file, boolean append)
```

Comment: I am using PrintStream but it doesn't append

Comment: Paste your code, so we can let you know what you have done wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`FileWriter` and `FileOutputStream` provide a constructor with an `append` flag. Just modify the referenced code accordingly

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"),true);
System.setOut(out);
```

Comment: Are you sure?  It seems to me that you may've put the parentheses in the wrong places.

Comment: @DavidWallace copy pasted the code and it works :)

Comment: @seteropere But not as desired (no append)