# Write all System.out into a file

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging, system.out

I have a large program in which I have used System.out for debugging. But I'd like to be able to log all System.out simultaneously to a file so even if my program isn't run in the console all the System.out will be written to a file and I will be able to see it in any moment the program is running or later.

Btw, it's not wise to crawl all the program and use a logger instead of System.out statements!

I tried `java -jar myjar.jar > sysout.txt` but it doesn't log the exceptions logged by java logger utility.

Comment: have you tried `java -jar myjar.jar 2>&1> sysout.txt` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write console output to a txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994255/how-to-write-console-output-to-a-txt-file)

Comment: There is no difference between > and 2>&1> what does it mean? It doesn't log the exceptions bis! @C.B.

Comment: @Johnny see bgamlath's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about `System.setOut(PrintStream)` ? You could insert this call in the initialization part of your program (start-up).

*Was previously a commment:*

And of course you can do the same with System.err - namely System.setErr(PrintStream), but better to a different file stream.

**In detail assuming an autoflushing appending and buffered file stream:**

```
    String file = ...;
    PrintStream ps = 
      new PrintStream(true, new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true)));
    System.setOut(ps);
```

Comment: And of course you can do the same with `System.err` - namely `System.setErr(PrintStream)`, but better to a different file stream.

Comment: I think it is better if you edited your answer to include the details of your comment above. That would make it a more complete answer. :)

Comment: I would also recommend this post for those who need both an output to a text file AND the system console https://www.baeldung.com/java-write-console-output-file

Answer (score 4):

The normal redirection  `command_name args > output` only redirect Standard Output. It does not redirect Standard Error stream, where usually the errors are logged in. To output both streams to the same file use,

```
command args &> filename
```

eg. `java -jar myjar.jar &> sysout.txt`

To redirect to different files, use

```
command args 1> output_file 2> error_file
```

eg. `java -jar myjar.jar 1> sysout.txt 2> errout.txt`

See more options at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: excellent! That's very nice however I find the Meno Hochschild's answer more flexible because it is Java-ish and I will be able to make daily dev logs!

Comment: @Johnny: Yup, that way you do not have to rely on the execution commands. :)