# Java: How to save console output to a text file?

Tags: java, file-io

For example, in the code, I have: `System.out.println("Hello World");`

The console will print: `Hello World`

So, I want to save the console output into a text file. Can anyone please hint me through this?

Comment: Have you googled `writing to a file in java` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994255/how-to-write-console-output-to-a-txt-file

Possible duplicate.

Comment: You can either write directly to a file, or redirect the output of the program to a file using OS commands (see redirection in linux for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System class provide you a way to dump output in different stream which is  `System#setOut(PrintStream out)`

Using this method you can pass you FileInputstream to `System.setOut` and you can save the console output.

```
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
System.setOut(printStream);
```

---

One interesting part of this question is though [`out`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java#System.0out) is declared as final in System class but still you reassign this by `System#setOut`.

Comment: No content found inside file. still having npEx.

Comment: please share the `exception stacktrace`

Answer (score 6):

Create a file, and set as the  out of the System class.

```
File file = new File("out.txt"); //Your file
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
System.setOut(ps);
System.out.println("This goes to out.txt");
```

Comment: Won't this rewrite the entry each time you want to write into the file?

Comment: nice, easy and will help

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, the output file is pretty empty...comments?

Comment: Doesn't work ! did not find any console text inside file . after getting NPEx.