# how to copy content of console to notepad using java

Tags: java

I created xml file using java. I just want to copy the xml file which was there in console to notepad through coding not through run configuration process...... I tried using

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("notepad.txt"));
System.setOut(out);
```

But the above line results in creation of notepad in particular location. But data is not copied inside the notepad. It results in empty notepad.

For creating xml: I used this below code which works fine

```
Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(); tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
tf.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");         Source src = new DOMSource(xmlDoc); Result dest = new StreamResult(System.out);
tf.transform(src, dest);
```

Anyone please help me on this....

Comment: By "notepad" do you mean the Windows text editor Notepad? Do you want a new Notepad window to open with your xml in it? Or do you want the XML to appear in an existing Notepad window? Is it OK if a new file is created, or is it important that Notepad contains an unsaved buffer?

Comment: Did you try `out.flush();` or `out.close();` at the end?

Comment: i want to save in new notepad file mate..

Comment: I didnt use that out.flush();

Comment: May be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994255/how-to-write-console-output-to-a-txt-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `StreamResult` class, so let's have a look at the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html#StreamResult(java.io.OutputStream)):

```
public StreamResult(OutputStream outputStream)
```

> Construct a StreamResult from a byte stream. Normally, a stream should
>   be used rather than a reader, so that the transformer may use
>   instructions contained in the transformation instructions to control
>   the encoding.

So, it acccepts the `OutputStream` as an argument, so you can either pass `out` or `new FileOutputStream("notepad.txt")` while creating an instance of `StreamResult` e,g.:

```
Result dest = new StreamResult(out);
out.close();

OR

OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("notepad.txt");
Result dest = new StreamResult(fileOutputStream);
fileOutputStream.close();
```

This would make sure the content gets written into the file. There is no need to use `System.out` for this.

**Update**

In order to print the same content to `console`, you will have to do another transformation with `StringWriter`, e.g.:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
tf.transform(src, result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

This would print the content into console.

Comment: Thanks mate... It works great ..... But only concern is like its not showing anything in console.. Everything is in notepad....

Comment: Is that not what you wanted (i.e. write everything into notepad file)?

Comment: yea!! but i want both!

Comment: @kumar updated the answer..

Comment: Iam able to get results both in notepad and console....Thanks for your help...