# Printing to file rather than terminal

Tags: java, file-writing

I've made a program for determining the time of a murder. The code I have right now prints exactly what it should to the terminal. I want it printed to a file. However, I'm not supposed to use `System.setOut()` for this assignment. I'm supposed to print to a file *instead* of to the terminal.

I know how to write a simple `String` into a file, the problem here is I already have methods for printing my results to the terminal, and I'm not sure how I "convert" those methods into printing into a file instead.

This is my two printing methods and main method:

Printing 2d array method:

```
public static void printArray2d(String[][] array2d){
    for(int i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < array2d[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(array2d[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Printing full report method:

```
public static void printReport(String[][] array2d, double arrayMin, double arrayMax){
    System.out.println("Time since death probability distribution");
    double hours = (arrayMax-arrayMin)/(array2d.length-1);
    System.out.printf("Each line corresponds to approximately %.2f hours\n", hours);
    System.out.printf("%.2f hours\n", arrayMin);
    printArray2d(array2d);
    System.out.printf("%.2f hours\n", arrayMax);
}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    double[] array = cooldownSamples(27, 1000);
    double[] counts = countsFromArray(array, 20);
    String[][] array2d = array2dFromCounts(counts);
    printReport(array2d, minFromArray(array), maxFromArray(array));
}
```

I can post the entire code if needed.

I am aware that there are similar questions asked earlier, but none of them gave me the help I needed. I also do not have enough reputation to ask follow-up questions to any of the answers given on those threads, so I was forced to ask a new question.

Thanks in advance for any help given!

Additional information:

Even though I said I'm not supposed to use `System.setOut()`, I have tried using the method and answers given in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994255/how-to-write-console-output-to-a-txt-file), without any luck. If the best and most efficient way of doing this is via `System.setOut()`, I do appreciate answers that make me understand how I can implement this and make it work in my code, even though I'm looking for an alternative method.

Comment: if `your_process` prints to the console, then you can easily print that to a file with `your_process > outfile`.

Comment: I don't get it. What is the problem with `System.setOut()` since you are ask to "_to print to a file instead of to the terminal_". `System.out` is just a stream, originally link to the terminal, if you redirect it to a file, this would be correct, it will not pass throught the terminal at all.

Comment: You can redirect the output (suggested above), you can use System.out + System.setOut, or you can change all of your System.out statements to use a different writer/PrintStream.

Comment: @AxelH I don't have a problem with it, myself. However, the assignment states I shouldn't use it. I would still appreciate an answer making use of `System.setOut()`, giving me an understanding of it, and making my code work with it. Sorry for the inconvenience though.

Comment: It state not to use specificly `System.setOut` or just like you said "_I'm supposed to print to a file instead of to the terminal_" ?

Comment: @AxelH the assignment says I'm supposed to print to a file instead of to the terminal. The teacher told me to not use `System.setOut()` yet, because we haven't been through it. I wouldn't fail the assignment if I did, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really simple: right now, you are using a (static) object `System.out` to do all printing. This object has methods to print, println, and so on.

Instead of using System.out, you create an instance of say [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) and call method on that object, like

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("whatever.txt");
writer.println("whatever");
writer.close();
```

That is all there is to this. Or even simpler, you could instantiate a [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) object. You could then do things such as:

```
 PrintStream out = System.out // or new PrintStream("filename");
 doStuff(out);
```

... with:

```
 public void doStuff(PrintStream out) {
   out.println...
```

And now you have one central place where you decided if you want to print to System.out - or somewhere else!

Comment: So I can literally change all my `System.out`-statements to `writer.print`-statements? If so, that _is_ really simple..

Comment: See my updates (about using PrintStream if you actually want to use either stdout or a file as destination).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have accepted your answer.

Comment: You are very welcome ;-)