# Does Java have an equivalent of c#'s Trace.WriteLine. I'm trying to write trace to console

Tags: java

I want tracing to appear in my java console when I set a non-zero trace level.
i.e. Java's equivalent of C#'s

```
Trace.WriteLine("hello");
```

Is there anything available like that? Can I get at "deployment.trace" at runtime? Is there an environment variable I can check?

Comment: by using basically and logging framework.

Comment: You're looking for slf4j (my preference) or log4j2.

Comment: Is `System.err::println` what you want?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino err's go to the console window too. If I could switch them off/on in the console then that would do me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994255/how-to-write-console-output-to-a-txt-file), but to summarize the answer it's like this:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("outputfile.txt"));
System.setOut(out);
```

After the line `System.setOut(out);` anything will be written in the file instead of the console.