# How to place Output from java to a .txt file.? JAVA

Tags: java

Currently trying to get the output of this program to a .txt file. I have to show the output in the console and also have it shown in the .txt file. I've looked and haven't seen a complete answer that would help me understand how to do it. Here is the program I'm working on. (complete beginner).

```
/*
 * Write a program that asks the user to enter today’s sales for five stores. The program should display a bar chart comparing each store’s sales. Create each bar in the bar chart by displaying a row of asterisks. Each asterisk should represent $100 of sales. Here is an example of the program’s output:
 *
 *  Enter today's sales for store 1: 1000 [Enter]
 *  Enter today's sales for store 2: 1200 [Enter]
 *  Enter today's sales for store 3: 1800 [Enter]
 *  Enter today's sales for store 4: 800 [Enter]
 *  Enter today's sales for store 5: 1900 [Enter]*
 *  SALES BAR CHART
 *  Store 1: **********
 *  Store 2: ************
 *  Store 3: ******************
 *  Store 4: ********
 *  Store 5: *******************
 */

import java.util.Scanner;


public class BarChart {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] store = new double[5];
        
        
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("Enter today\'s sales for store %d: ", i + 1);
            store[i] = userInput.nextDouble();
        }
        
        System.out.println("\nSALES BAR CHART");
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("Store %d: ", i + 1);
            
            for(int c = 0; c < store[i]/100; c++)
                System.out.print("*");
            
            System.out.println();
        }
        
        userInput.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write console output to a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994255/how-to-write-console-output-to-a-txt-file)

Answer (score 1):

Most operation system allow redirecting output to file:

```
% java BaseChart > file.txt
```

or using `tee`, output can be shown and saved to file:

```
% java BaseChart | tee file.txt
```

---

if this *must* be done in Java, there are some alternatives:

1 - create a `PrintWriter`, `BufferedWriter` or any `Writer` to write to a file, add print statements similar to the `System.out.print` ones. This site should have answers about how to do it.

2 - extend a `FilterOutputStream` to write to a file and to the original `System.out`, and set the filter as new `System.out` (this is doing the same job as `tee`). Also lots of post on StackOverflow about `FilterOutputStream`
<sup>this is mostly indicated for bigger projects with lots of output</sup>

...

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner` can't be used for writing purposes, only reading. I like to use a `BufferedWriter` to write to text files.

`out.write("some text");` //That's how you write text to the file.

`out.newLine();` //That's how you made new line for your text.

Remember that you in this case, you should first create this file on your computer ex. `text.txt` and after that you must replace `"path/filename.txt"` with particular path to this file ex. `"C:\\text.txt"`, more information you can find there: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html)

Working code bellow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] store = new double[5];

    try(Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("path/filename.txt"));) {

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter today\'s sales for store %d: ", i + 1);
            out.write("Enter today\'s sales for store " + (i + 1) +": ");
            store[i] = userInput.nextDouble();
            out.write(String.valueOf(store[i]));
            out.newLine();
        }

        System.out.println("\nSALES BAR CHART");
        out.write("\nSALES BAR CHART");
        out.newLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Store %d: ", i + 1);
            out.write("Store " + (i + 1) + ": ");

            for(int c = 0; c < store[i]/100; c++) {
                System.out.print("*");
                out.write("*");
            }

            out.newLine();
            System.out.println();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Additionally I used **try-with-resources**. It's a better approach to closed resources. Here is a documentation about this mechanism: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Thank you. I tried the code as written, but it still didn't print the output into the file. I tried with making a .txt file for it to right to but no luck. Then I tried to tweak it with FileWriter but just errors (pretty sure Im using the wrong syntax)

Comment: You should replace "path/filename.txt" with particular path to your file for example: "C:\\text.txt". I will update my answer with this.